# Erro ao tentar instalar SASS/COMPASS

Tags: ruby, sass

Estou com um problema ao instalar o SASS e COMPASS no meu Mac, está dando um erro de permissão. Já liberei o ler e gravar arquivos no finder.

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
>       Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/cache/sass-3.2.14.gem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adicione `sudo` antes do comando que está rodando

antes:

> comando

depois

> sudo comando

Comment: Funcionou Hernandes.